# How to populate formulae in extended columns of a table that uses a data source

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, spreadsheet

I have a SQL Server Database data source that loads in to a table in Excel.
In that worksheet, I have extended the table to include additional columns (that aren't from the data source).

When I refresh the data, the additional columns that I added aren't populating the formulae through every newly-added row of that table.

I would like to hit 'Refresh', and if the data from the source goes from 160 rows, to 165 rows; for the extended columns to automatically populate through for the additional 5 rows that have been added.

I have tried just simply dragging the formulae but I don't want to do this every time, I want it to be automated.

I have also tried looking in Power Query - I have tried adding an additional column in Power Query but it seems I can only add additional columns that are related to my data source.

Comment: just tested this with a table loaded from Powerquery and the table does extend the formulas entered when the source changes. can you post a sample file?